# Some dates disappear and reappear on scroll in JTCalendar Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, calendar, xcode11.4, jtcalendar

I am trying to setup a calendar in my app using JTCalendar library but unfortunately i have this issue when sometimes i scroll through the app, the month in view looses the dates as described in the attached picture. I have tried to find out any information or questions in regards to this kind of issue but all was in vain. Am a bit new on this library, could anyone help me to solve this. Thanks for your time.

[image]
[image]

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       popWithSwipe()


       PLmonthArr = ["Styczeń","Luty","Marzec","Kwiecień","Maj","Czerwiec","Lipiec","Sierpień","Wrzesień","Październik","Listopad","Grudzień"]


       calendarManager.menuView = calendarMenuView
       calendarManager.contentView = calendarContentView
       calendarManager.settings.weekDayFormat = JTCalendarWeekDayFormat.single

       calendarManager.delegate = self
       calendarManager.setDate(Date())



   }

   //MARK: View Will Appear

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        currentLang = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"language")as?String ?? "pl-PL"
       setTextOnLanguageChange(lang:UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"language")as?String ?? "pl-PL")


      calendarManager.reload()

   }
   public func calendar(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!, prepareMenuItemView menuItemView: UIView!, date: Date!)
   {

       if let headerLabel = menuItemView as? UILabel{

           headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment .center
           headerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Comfortaa-Light", size: 20)
           headerLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
           headerLabel.textColor  = UIColor.gray




           let formatter = DateFormatter()
           formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
           formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
           let monthYear  = formatter.string(from:date)

            print(monthYear)
           let yearFormatter = DateFormatter()
           yearFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy"
           let CurrentYear  = yearFormatter.string(from:date)
          print(currentLang)
           if currentLang == "pl-PL"{
               headerLabel.text = setmonthLang(monthYear: monthYear,CurrentYear:CurrentYear).uppercased()
           }else //if currentLang == "en"
           {
               headerLabel.text = monthYear.uppercased()
           }



       }


   }


   func numberOfMondaysInMonth(month: Int, forYear year: Int) -> Int?
   {
       let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendar.Identifier.gregorian)!
       calendar.firstWeekday = 2 // 2 == Monday


       // First monday in month:
       let comps = NSDateComponents()
       comps.month = month
       comps.year = year
       comps.weekday = calendar.firstWeekday
       comps.weekdayOrdinal = 1
       guard let first = calendar.date(from: comps as DateComponents)  else {
           return nil
       }

       // Last monday in month:
       comps.weekdayOrdinal = -1
       guard let last = calendar.date(from: comps as DateComponents)  else {
           return nil
       }

       // Difference in weeks:
       let weeks = calendar.components(.weekOfMonth, from: first, to: last, options: [])
       return (weeks.weekOfMonth ?? 0) + 1
   }



   func setmonthLang(monthYear:String,CurrentYear:String)->String
     {
     if monthYear.contains("January")
       {

          return "\(PLmonthArr[0]), \(CurrentYear)"
       }
       else if monthYear.contains("February")
     {
          return "\(PLmonthArr[1]), \(CurrentYear)"
       }
       else if monthYear.contains("March"){
          return "\(PLmonthArr[2]), \(CurrentYear)"
       }
       else if monthYear.contains("April"){
           return "\(PLmonthArr[3]), \(CurrentYear)"
       }
       else if monthYear.contains("May"){
           return "\(PLmonthArr[4]), \(CurrentYear)"
       }
       else if monthYear.contains("June"){
           return "\(PLmonthArr[5]), \(CurrentYear)"
       }
       else if monthYear.contains("July"){
           return "\(PLmonthArr[6]), \(CurrentYear)"
       }
       else if monthYear.contains("August"){
         return "\(PLmonthArr[7]), \(CurrentYear)"
       }
       else if monthYear.contains("September"){
           return "\(PLmonthArr[8]), \(CurrentYear)"
       }
       else if monthYear.contains("October"){
          return "\(PLmonthArr[9]), \(CurrentYear)"
       }
       else if monthYear.contains("November"){
          return "\(PLmonthArr[10]), \(CurrentYear)"
       }
       else{
           return "\(PLmonthArr[11]), \(CurrentYear)"
   }
   }







   public func calendar(_ calendar: JTCalendarManager!, prepareDayView dayView: (UIView & JTCalendarDay)!)
   {



       if dayView.isFromAnotherMonth(){
                   dayView.isHidden = true
               }

               let mydayview=dayView as! JTCalendarDayView


               mydayview.textLabel.font = UIFont(name:"Montserrat-Regular", size:13)
               mydayview.circleRatio = 2

              mydayview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

               mydayview.circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 1
               mydayview.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
               mydayview.isFromAnotherMonth = false

               let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
       dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
               dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

               let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: mydayview.date)
               print(dateStr)

               if(isAVailableOnSelectedDate(dateStr: dateStr)){

                   let now = Date()
                   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

                   print(dateFormatter.string(from: now))

                   if  let currentDate = calendarManager.date() {

                    let currentDateString = String(describing: currentDate)

                       if  dateFormatter.string(from: now) == currentDateString.prefix(10){

                           mydayview.circleView.isHidden = false      
                           mydayview.circleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
                           mydayview.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.black


                       }


                       else{

                           mydayview.circleView.isHidden = false
                           mydayview.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
                           mydayview.circleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

                       }
                   }

               }
               else if calendarManager.dateHelper.date(calendarContentView.date, isTheSameMonthThan: mydayview.date)
              {
                  mydayview.circleView.isHidden = true;
                //  mydayview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                   // mydayview.dotView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                   mydayview.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.gray
               }


               if calendarManager.dateHelper.date(Date(), isTheSameDayThan: mydayview.date){
                   mydayview.circleView.isHidden = false
                   mydayview.circleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                   mydayview.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
                   mydayview.layer.borderWidth = 1

               } else if mydayview.date > Date() || mydayview.date < Date(){

                  mydayview.layer.borderWidth = 0

       }

   }
```